# Excel formula counting specific cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

=COUNTIF(B25:M25,"*S-1*")

My question is when a cell contains "S-15", it is being counted as a "S-1".
How can I specify "S-1" only?

Comment: I don't have enough information to tell what is wrong with your workbook but when I do a countif, it doesn't include "S-15"s.. Check the formatting of your cells and make them text only as this could help.

Comment: To me it counts correctly. I tried with S-1; S-11; S-15 - It gives the count of 1 when i search for either of the three

Comment: We need more information, Wayne

Comment: Problem caused by simple syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways, here is one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B25:M25="S-1"))
```